# Ant colony network in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make a 3D network similar to the inside from an ant colony by using Geometry Nodes. I am a bit clueless on how to start, maybe someone could give some pointers.

[image]
[image]
This is an example of how I imagine the shape to be, it is an ant home filled with aluminium

Comment: In here might be some fundamentals that can be used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61mpAo1I3FQ&t=1947s&ab_channel=fartsimpson